# How do you add a NODE to your database root in the Firebase Realtime Database Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

The Console ONLY allows you to add a CHILD to the root. You cannot add a NODE in the Windows Console or in the Chrome Console.

Comment: Your root database location is like EXAMPLE.firebaseio.com, so anything you add to it will be like EXAMPLE.firebaseio.com/testnode. You can't add a node/child that's adjacent to the root.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want or need a 2nd root node?

Comment: I don't want to add a 2nd root node.  I want to add several different nodes to/under the root. I will then add children under those several different nodes. As it is, clicking on the + sign on the root only allows you to add a child (with a value) to the root. The first node under the root could be Region01, the second Region02, etc. Then under the Region01 node I will have children Message1 (with a value), Message2 (with a value), etc. and similarly for Region02, Region03, etc.

Comment: Have you found a way to do it using console UI?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I got the question right, the following is desired:

```
/db-root
  /newly-added-node-1
  /newly-added-node-2
  ...
```

Had the same problem recently. There was also such a warning in the Firebase database console section:

> Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance. Select a key with fewer records to edit or view in realtime.

If this is the case, you can simply add a node through the URL string. So, just visit:

http://console.firebase.google.com/project/${project-id}/database/${db-root}/data/${new-node-name}

And you'll be able to add data to the new node.

Hope this helps. Cheers!